# How do I detach from the shell when running pywebio app in server mode?

Tags: python

I am running a simple web app using pywebio. If I use the start_server, it doesn't detach from the shell (is it expected to?)

I can background python itself, but that doesn't seem the right thing to do. If I dockerize this app, the docker run does not yield the shell.

What is the right way to handle this?

```
from pywebio.output import *
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio import *


def myfunc():
  ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
  start_server(myfunc, port=1234)
```

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish? Why would you want to detach? The usual way to run a server is to have it run as a system service or daemon, and have it output log files where you can see them from a terminal.

Comment: OK got it. So I have to run this as a system service to have it running. For some reason, I assumed that the start_server automatically daemonize this. Thanks!

Comment: `system service` is a correct way for common cases, but if you need to run process in background temporarily, just run it in [background](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/)